# Statsmodels (Patsy) illegal variable name / 'Series' object is not callable Error

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, regression, statsmodels

**Update:**

**The error might have been caused by the fact that there is also a variable named "Q" in my dataset which conflicts the Q function. In this case, how do I elegantly solve it?**

---

**Update:
You can download my dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/47p66s718fcgjve/exp.csv?dl=0).**

---

I am running a simple OLS regression with statsmodels and pandas dataframe as following:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("exp.csv")
#df is a dataframe that I have containing many variable names such as AAPL, SPY, INF, etc.
for column in df: 
    result=sm.ols(formula="SPY"+" ~ "+column, data=df).fit()
```

However, one of the column name in df is `INF`. I guess maybe `INF` is a reserved word for pasty, the code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 155, in from_formula
    missing=missing)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/formula/formulatools.py", line 65, in handle_formula_data
    NA_action=na_action)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 310, in dmatrices
    NA_action, return_type)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 165, in _do_highlevel_design
    NA_action)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 62, in _try_incr_builders
    formula_like = ModelDesc.from_formula(formula_like)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/desc.py", line 165, in from_formula
    value = Evaluator().eval(tree, require_evalexpr=False)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/desc.py", line 400, in eval
    result = self._evaluators[key](self, tree)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/desc.py", line 221, in _eval_any_tilde
    exprs = [evaluator.eval(arg) for arg in tree.args]    
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/desc.py", line 400, in eval
    result = self._evaluators[key](self, tree)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/desc.py", line 355, in _eval_number
    "only allowed with **", tree)
patsy.PatsyError: numbers besides '0' and '1' are only allowed with **
    SPY ~ INF
          ^^^
```

**I have also tried using the Q function:**

```
result=sm.ols(formula="SPY"+" ~ "+"Q('INF')", data=df).fit()
```

However, it gives me the following error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 155, in from_formula
    missing=missing)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/formula/formulatools.py", line 65, in handle_formula_data
    NA_action=na_action)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 310, in dmatrices
    NA_action, return_type)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 165, in _do_highlevel_design
    NA_action)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 70, in _try_incr_builders
    NA_action)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/build.py", line 696, in design_matrix_builders
    NA_action)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/build.py", line 443, in _examine_factor_types
    value = factor.eval(factor_states[factor], data)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 566, in eval
    data)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 551, in _eval
    inner_namespace=inner_namespace)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/compat.py", line 36, in call_and_wrap_exc
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ap248/.local/easybuild/software/2017/Core/miniconda2/4.3.27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 166, in eval
    + self._namespaces))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by ignoring the formula and use the direct interface instead:

```
for column in df: 
    Y,X = df[column], df['SPY']
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    result=sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
```

It looks to me that the interface still has some issues and is not easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

According to this link: http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtins-reference.html#patsy.builtins.Q you can use Q("var") in the formula to get rid of the error.

The following code should work.

```
model = sm.ols('SPY ~ Q("INF")',data=df).fit()
```

A full example

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['SPY','INF','X'])

model = sm.ols('SPY ~ Q("INF")',data=df).fit()
```

Comment: But why did it give me the series object not callable error priviously? The code seems the same to me.

Comment: The error might have been caused by the fact that there is also a variable named "Q" in my dataset which conflicts the Q function. In this case, how do I elegantly solve it? @sukhbinder

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the column name, statsmodels can't fit regression line with "inf" in column name for example INF --> Infraction or anything else.